# Python tornado, conditional template extension

Tags: python, templates, tornado

I'm using tornadoweb to build a web service. I have two different templates that contains the html `head`, the navbar, and all the UI that is common to all pages server by the service. The first, `base.html` contains navbar items and other html elements displayed to authenticated users only. The second, `base_anon.html` is lighter and contains a few items that are available to anonymous users.

Now I'm creating a third template that will contain the actual content of the page. I would like this template to extend either `base_anon.html` or `base.html` depending whether a user is authenticated or not. The variable `user` will be Falsy if the user is not authenticated. Is there a way to do a conditional template extension?

I tried the following:

```
{% if user %}
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% else %}
    {% extends "base_anon.html" %}
{% end %}
```

Which, when rendered by tornado generates the following stack trace (copied only the end of the stack):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/template.py", line 291, in _generate_python
    ancestors[0].generate(writer)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/template.py", line 416, in generate
    self.body.generate(writer)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/template.py", line 429, in generate
    chunk.generate(writer)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/template.py", line 510, in generate
    self.body.generate(writer)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/template.py", line 429, in generate
    chunk.generate(writer)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/template.py", line 398, in generate
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

I do not have more information to provide that could explain this error. Neither could I find any information in the [docs](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/template.html) about a conflict between `if` and `extends` statements. Any idea why this error shows up? If this is actually expected, how else may I use a different base template depending on the value of some variable?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible to do what you're asking for. If the `{% extends %}` directive is used it must appear at top level and its argument must be a constant; there is no way to change which template you are extending.

Instead, consider using different top-level templates depending on whether or not there is a logged-in user, and encapsulating the common elements in `UIModules`. Or put all of the `{% if %}` directives in the base template, perhaps around the `{% block %}` definitions.